# JDBC/Spring - execute sql query to get iterator of results

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

So far I have been using 'SimpleJdbcTemplate'  and used a 'RowCallbackHadler' to process the whole result of the query. At the moment I would like to receive an iterator-like object, which I could query for the next table row whe interested. Is the following behaviour possible in Spring/jdbc (preferrably slpring)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the JdbcTemplate method queryforRowSet

```
public SqlRowSet queryForRowSet(String sql,
                                Object... args)
                         throws DataAccessException
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForRowSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ResultSetExtractor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html) instead of a `RowCallbackHadler`. Methods in `JdbcTemplate` accepting the latter will accept the former too.